# full screen editor in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, plugins, fullscreen, eclipse-juno

There are a few plugins that allow full screen editing in Eclipse but I can't find any that I can install on Juno. Does anyone know whether such a thing exists?

When I search for "full screen" in the marketplace, for example, several examples show up but none of them are installable. (Why the marketplace shows plugins that can't be installed, I've no idea.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check this plugin:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fullscreen-mode
it works on eclipse juno. After installing choose Window Menu ->full screen to go fullscreen