# How to get Full Screen View in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo

Is there any option to show full Screen View for Eclipse Indigo. There is no option to add this plugin in market place

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498086/full-screen-editor-in-eclipse-juno

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fullscreen-mode , it works on eclipse 3.4+ (Ganymede or later). After installing choose Window Menu ->full screen to go fullscreen.